# How to generate a uniquie ID containing 5 digits in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently creating a website using Django, I have gotten the Admin Form to work however I want it so when I create an Owner Django generates a random ID containing a specific amount of numbers and for that ID to be displayed next to the Owners Firtsname and Last name. Below is the models.py used in the django:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Suburb = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    postcode = models.IntegerField()
    owner_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.First_Name +" "+ self.Last_Name


class Pet_Description(models.Model):
    description_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pet_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    weight_in_kg = models.IntegerField()
    height_in_cm = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    overweight = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    healthy = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    indoor_or_outdoor = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pet_name

class Booking(models.Model):
    booking_ID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.booking_ID 


class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_ID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    booking_ID = models.ForeignKey(Booking, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.payment_ID

class Pet_Illness(models.Model):
    pet_ID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=CASCADE)
    type_of_illness = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description_of_illness = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_of_illness + ": " + self.description_of_illness

class Pet_History(models.Model):
    pet_history_ID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    pet_ID = models.ForeignKey(Pet_Description, on_delete=CASCADE)
    Visited_vet_before = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    First_time_of_illness = models.DateField()
    Special_Medication = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Medication_Description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pet_history_ID
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what is the error here and what is the expected outcome.

Comment: Is your main issue that the UUID is far larger than five digits and not suitable for display? It's that large for a reason -- at only five digits, even a few users will get the same ID if it is truly randomly assigned. If you really want to be random but only five digits, you will basically need to make a big shuffled list of all the unique numbers, and then assign them in that random order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [shortuuid](https://pypi.org/project/shortuuid/)

And save manually during model creation

here is the code, this code will generate random digit

```
import shortuuid
s = shortuuid.ShortUUID(alphabet="0123456789")
otp = s.random(length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can store uuid like this in views.py:**

```
# importing uuid
import uuid
  
# creating an instance of
# uuid object
test = uuid.uuid4()
  
# creating a instance of 
# Model
obj = modelName.objects.create(field_name = test)
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

universally unique identifier (UUID) is a 128 bit number. [this article might help in better understanding UUID](https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2020-01/uuid-primary-key/)

> The probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion version-4 UUIDs is one in a billion.It means that if you produce “every second” an UUID for 3,266,108 year, your collision chance is .000000001.

or

You could use shortuuid [shortuuid](https://github.com/skorokithakis/shortuuid)